# Eco templates - Some artefacts in code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, coffeescript, eco

Using eco template I form follow code:

```
<% if @is_completed : %>
   <span class="label">completed</span>
<% end %>
```

But after rendering I see some artifacts in my code:

```
<div class="large-3 columns">
    <span class="label">
        completed
    </span>
    "9"
</div>
```

p.s.

I've tried to mark my code by characters "a", "b", "c", ... :

```
<div class="large-3 columns">a
    b<% if @is_completed: %>c
        d<span class="label">e
            completed
         f</span>g
    h<%end%>i
j</div>
```

And here is what I've seen >>> h **9** i:

```
<div class="large-3 columns">"abcd"
    <span class="label">
        e completed f
    </span>
    "gh9ij"
</div>
```

But the numbers are different? Not only "9".

What's wrong?

Comment: It seems to be as that `if` clause is not the issue here.

Comment: what's the purpose behind the `:` in the `if`?

Comment: And where is that `9` coming from? :)

Comment: >> _And where is that 9 coming from? :)_

This is the **MAIN** question.

Comment: >> _what's the purpose behind the : in the if?_
This is a conndition for "true" or "false".

Comment: >>_It seems to be as that if clause is not the issue here. _
It seems to be as <% end %> doesn't work properly.

Comment: @UriAgassi the `:` is there for delimiting purposes in Eco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello everyone,**

**Firstly,** I'm sorry because at the beginning I couldn't find similar question at *Stackoverflow*.

**Secondly,** I know the answer.

**There is the same issue:**
[Eco template renders integer when using 'end' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035900/eco-template-renders-integer-when-using-end-statement)

> **@Phoeniks** tells that installing node.js could solve the issue. And it's true. But I must supplement him. You should specify path to
>   Node.js in the Environment Variables in "Path".

Thank to everyone.